# Why would stored passwords be cleared automatically in IE11 or Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, internet-explorer-11

Every so often, the stored passwords I allow IE11 or Chrome to store (on Windows 7), seem to be cleared and I have to re-enter them. I have searched online but cant find any information why this would ever happen?

It is not related to updating or installing anything, and I haven't cleared browsing history, cookies, etc. when it happens. It seems to just happen by itself every so often. I am wondering if there is something malicious potentially behind it.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this could occur?

(p.s. I'm a windows developer and otherwise fairly familiar technically with browsers, registry, security, etc.)

Comment: Whether you have changed the IE or Chrome settings? Try to reset the browser. please refer to these articles: [Edge browser reset](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/reset-microsoft-edge-default-settings/), [Chrome browser reset](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1007476/).

Comment: So how does that answer my question? For starters I did say IE11 and Chrome, not Edge.

Comment: It's my mistake, about reset IE settings you could refer [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings).

Comment: I don't believe its due to any settings. They (logins/passwords) can be there for months then suddenly all disappear overnight on the same night. If you think it is, then perhaps you could suggest exactly which settings could cause that to occur instead of me trashing all ?